# Does a spam trap open e-mails?

Tags: spam

Does a spam trap open e-mails? Because my list contains a lot of spam traps and the only solution is to keep only the openers in my list.

can any one help me please.

Comment: What do you mean by opening emails? Reading its contents?

Comment: I mean those people who open emails sent to them

Answer (score 1):

No, spamtraps don't open emails and it's always a good idea to remove non openers from your list. 
Abandoned email addresses are recycled as spamtraps so a legit address that is in your list from a long time may be a spamtrap today.

Moreover, non openers don't provide any benefit to you. Removing them decreases your email volume and increases your open rate, both of these metrics influence your reputation.